# Showing two vectors are orthogonal

Tags: differential-geometry

> From do Carmo book:
>
> "Let $\alpha(t)$ be a parametrized curve which does not pass through the origin. if $\alpha(t_{0})$ is the point of the trace of $\alpha$ closest to the origin and $\alpha'(t_{0})\neq 0$, show that the position vector $\alpha(t_{0})$ is orthogonal to $\alpha'(t_{0})$"

So we know that $|\alpha(t_{0})|$ is minimum $\alpha'(t_{0})\neq 0$ and we need to prove that $\alpha(t_{0})\cdot \alpha'(t_{0})=0$?

Comment: Differentiate $t \mapsto |a(t)|^2$. What will the value be at a $\min$?

Comment: @copper.hat why do we look at $|\alpha(t)|^2$? and not $|\alpha(t)|$?

Comment: You can, but it is easier to differentiate the square.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to almost rewrite the above. I didn't notice it until I was done. I tacked on a few extra words so the solution flows better for the OP.

Comment: @copper.hat: Would you mind putting your comment as an answer so the question can be answered?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood: Your answer looks good.

Comment: @copper.hat: I just didn't want it to seem like I just rewrote what you had. I genuinely missed the comments when typing.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood: Don't think about it, just focus on answering the OP's question. I have my MSE T-shirt :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember the wording of this problem completely throwing me off as well. Since $\alpha(t)$ is closest to the origin at $t=t_0$ then $g(t) = \|\alpha(t)\|$ has a minimum at $t_0$. But $g: I \to \mathbb{R}$ and so $g'(t_0) = ?$ Once you figure out the $?$ the problem works itself out.

Comment: So the derivative of $|\alpha({t_0})|>0$ and $\alpha'(t_{0})\neq 0$?

Comment: If $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ has a minimum or maximum at $x_0 \in I$, then $f'(x_0) = 0$. This is a result from first year calculus.

Comment: Sorry, thought about the second derivative.
 the derivative of $ |\alpha(t_0)|=0$ and $\alpha'(t_0)\neq 0$

Comment: Yup, that is correct :).

Comment: If this solution satisfies you, you can accept so the question is closed.

Comment: So $0=\frac{\alpha(t_0)\cdot \alpha'(t_{0})}{|\alpha(t_{0})|}$ we know that $|\alpha(t_{0})|\text{ , }\alpha(t_{0}),\alpha'(t_{0})\neq 0$ so $\alpha(t_{0})\text{ , } \alpha'(t_{0})$ orthogonal

Comment: yes, that i correct.